# Backbone.Marionette: Render LayoutView without application region

Tags: javascript, marionette

I am trying to render the application's layout view without using an application-level region (they are deprecated).

```
MyLayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    el: 'body',

    regions: {
        ...
    },

    onBeforeShow: function() {
        // render child regions
    }
});

App = new Marionette.Application();
App.on('start', function() {
    this.view = new MyLayoutView();
    this.view.render();
});
```

The call `view.render();` doesn't trigger the show, and attach events, so the view's elements don't get added to the DOM. So, how should we create top-level layout views without using a region?

Comment: It seems like an oversight to me. I created a codepen that shows your issue: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpNLvw. Have you considered logging an issue with Marionette? For now, I would use an app region

Comment: As I understand [docs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.3/marionette.application.html#application-regions) you can set your layout view into `App.rootView`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is to create the layout view on the body element without using a top level region.

It makes sense, because typically body has multiple children elements. If region was defined on the body, then there would only be one single element under body (represented by the view attached to that top level region).

As for the show event not being triggered, you can just hook up to render events (render or before:render):

`onRender: function() {
        // render child regions
}`